# Operating System Assembly language for different architectures

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86

I am new to this subject so forgive my ignorance?

I just started learning assembly for x86 processors on my linux system. I wrote a simple bootloader which worked but was specific to x86. Also I understand the registers etc are very different for intel and amd or 32 bit and 64 bits. So how is an operating system or application written for various architectures at the same time. Yes applications are operating system specific but shouldn't they be cpu specific also. Like when they are compiled into machine code, they need to be made for one type of processor(since registers etc are different for different architectures)? So how do they do it?

Or is it possible that all x86 has common registers and instruction set like athlon, pentium, 
i3, i5 etc and it is only different between x86 and 64 bit architecture?

Comment: many of the current processors today can still process x86 programs even their architecture is x64 and if you are planning to make a software the works both on x64 and x86, make it in x86 architecture.

Answer (score 0):

What you said at the end is correct - all x86 has a common set of instructions, although the details of what it does under the hood is obviously very different. For example, on Intel hardware you actually have hidden registers which the x86 assembly instructions can't actually access.

The parts of the operating system that are written in assembly would require different assembly instructions for different architectures (x86 vs PPC vs ARM etc...)

The parts of the operating system that are written in c may also have some differences, for example when moving to x64 you can no longer assume that a pointer is 4 bytes. To deal with these differences in the C level the code would typically use lots of #ifdefs to deal with the differences.

This is of course a very big topic and the above is just a very general overview.

Comment: the x in x86 has some history - it was originally 8086 instruction set. Then 80186, 80286, 80386, etc... each set introduced new capabilities. For example 80386 introduced 32 bit registers.

The instruction set is designed to be backwards compatible. In the case of 8 to 16 to 32 to 64 bits the register name keeps "growing"

rax is a 64 bit register, eax is the lower 32, ax is the lower 16, al is the lower 8. This way x86 instruction using eax would still work on an x64 CPU

Comment: thank you..with assembly things become much clearer about internal working...been trying high level languages for sometime but didn't know what was happening inside until now..thanks again

Comment: And in assembly coding there is code16 to make the code 16 bit. So is this what tell the processor which architecture to use like 16 bit or 32bit or 64 bit? Like we can't use a mix of both right?

Answer (score 0):

When you start looking at low-level code (e.g. boot code, kernels, etc) the idea that high level language code is portable is nonsense. There are a lot of things where different CPUs need different code but no high level language has support. This includes switching CPU modes, setting up paging, storing/loading task state (during task switches), etc.

To work around this you end up using non-portable code (assembly). For kernel code this typically means using things like conditional code (e.g. `#ifdef i386`) and shifting the non-portable parts into special (CPU/architecture specific) directories; so that the majority of the code is portable (but a small part has to be rewritten for each different case).

The same applies to boot code; but here it gets a little messier because there may be several different "pre-boot environments" (e.g. BIOS and UEFI) for the exact same CPU. I think everyone deals with this in their own different way.

Note that 80x86 has "historically related" registers and instruction sets. This does not mean the same code can work on all 80x86 CPUs (or even the same CPU in different modes). There's several modes (mainly 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit) that require different code, and then there's several extensions (3DNow, MMX, SSE, AVX) that add additional registers and may or may not exist. There are also parts of the CPU (e.g. performance monitoring) which are "model specific".

Comment: The boot code for PC's runs in 16 bit real mode, but uses prefixes on instructions to get 32 bit operands as needed. Years ago, the BIOS calls for disk I/O were extended to use 64 bit addresses for sector addresses, but it's still in 16 bit mode, so data has to be read in the first 1 megabyte of memory. There's a BIOS call to switch into protected mode that takes pointers to X86 specific tables to do this, which would switch into 32 bit or 64 bit protected mode.

Comment: @rcgldr: Nobody ever uses that BIOS function (it's much easier to do mode switches yourself) and it will never support 64-bit (which requires paging). The boot code for PCs with UEFI is typically 64-bit code (but 32-bit code is needed for older 32-bit UEFI systems). The BIOS is currently being deprecated; but even for BIOS often you'll have a "thunking wrapper" around the BIOS functions so that you can use 32-bit protected mode for the majority of your boot code.

Comment: "The BIOS is currently being deprecated" - Perhaps the BIOS function to switch into protected mode is not used by current operating systems, but I'm not aware of a standard programming interface for SATA, USB floppies, or network devices, so how is the I/O performed for these devices during boot up without using the BIOS?